# Calculating percentage growth month by month

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a basic database for a retail store (4 tables) and am trying to run a query that will calculate the percentage growth (or decline) month by month in revenue for the store. The `ORDERS` table holds the `OrderPrice` info for each month.

I am struggling to find a query that will do this, does anyone know if one exists?

The DB is here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qS515ShyFGxgj4h6Ga6HA3/0#&togetherjs=009rG6HwUe

I have come up with this so far to `SUM` the revenue totals month by month:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Coalesce(MONTHNAME(ORDERS.OrderDate), 'Grand Total') AS OrderDate, 
SUM(ORDERS.OrderPrice) as SumOrderPrice  
FROM ORDERS
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(ORDERS.OrderDate) with ROLLUP)
AS T;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18722270/109122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're close:

I tweaked your statement, and came up with the following. I made one notable assumption - that you want the output sorted by month number, with the rollup value last. If you ultimately need to show a list that runs October of one year through September of the next, you'll need to put in a little more work.

```
SELECT Coalesce(OrderDate, 'Grand Total') AS OrderDate
      ,SumOrderPrice
FROM (
      SELECT MONTHNAME(ORDERS.OrderDate) as OrderDate
            ,SUM(ORDERS.OrderPrice) as SumOrderPrice
            ,MONTH(ORDERS.OrderDate) as MonthNum
      FROM ORDERS
      WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
      GROUP BY
            MONTHNAME(ORDERS.OrderDate)
           ,MONTH(ORDERS.OrderDate) with ROLLUP
     ) AS T
ORDER BY COALESCE(MonthNum,13);
```

Here's the modified [DB-Fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wLDMS3HyMkQCjxAQeKgvcJ/0), including my version of the query.

What I changed, and why:

- First, the `USE GUITARWORLD` at the top of your DB-Fiddle made the set-up code not run. In the future, please ensure that what you've posted in a DB-Fiddle does run successfully - having that just flat-out fail is a bad start :-).
- Your `GROUP BY` isn't grouping by a value in the `SELECT` list. That isn't always a mistake, but that meant your `COALESCE(MONTHNAME())` didn't work. I changed the `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY` the `MONTHNAME()` results alone, and moved the `COALESCE` to the outer query, to ensure that the results from that weren't causing problems with the grouping. Since I wasn't using `SELECT *`, I also needed to explicitly return `SumOrderPrice`.

Initially, the results listed April, then March, then the Grand Total. I was reasonably certain you'd want to see the months in numerical order, instead of alphabetical (or indeterminate) order, so I added `MONTH(Orders.OrderDate)` as a new column in the inner query; added it to the `GROUP BY` (no change to the results, as a given month number will always have the matching given name), and sorted the results by `MonthNum` (adding the `COALESCE` to force the Grand Total to show up last.

---

For the next step, we'll use a variable:

```
SET @Last_Month_SumOrderPrice := 0;

SELECT OrderDate, SumOrderPrice, Monthly_Pct_Change
FROM (
      SELECT OrderDate
            ,SumOrderPrice
            ,CASE WHEN @Last_Month_SumOrderPrice = 0
               THEN NULL
               ELSE (SumOrderPrice - @Last_Month_SumOrderPrice) * 100.00 / @Last_Month_SumOrderPrice
             END as Monthly_Pct_Change
            ,@Last_Month_SumOrderPrice := SumOrderPrice
            ,MonthNum
      FROM (
            SELECT MONTHNAME(ORDERS.OrderDate) as OrderDate, 
                   SUM(ORDERS.OrderPrice) as SumOrderPrice,
                   MONTH(ORDERS.OrderDate) as MonthNum
            FROM ORDERS
            WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
            GROUP BY MONTHNAME(ORDERS.OrderDate),
                     MONTH(ORDERS.OrderDate)
           ) AS T
      ORDER BY MonthNum) as SQ
ORDER BY MonthNum;
```

We take the basic query you already had, and add in a variable, `@Last_Month_SumOrderPrice`, to track the SumOrderPrice from the previous month as we go through the data. While the `SELECT` list data is being processed, the variable will retain its value from the last row.

This gives us access to the current and previous months' `SumOrderPrice` values. Calculating the percentage from there is trivial. I'm setting the value to NULL to avoid divide by zero errors.

We put another query outside the existing ones; otherwise, the value assigned to the variable would be output in every row.

Note that I've included an `ORDER BY` in the `SQ` sub-query, and in the outer query as well, both on `MonthNum`. The one in the sub-query guarantees the rows are processed in the correct order; the one in the outer query guarantees the final result is displayed in the correct order. It may be likely that the final result would be ordered correctly without the outer `ORDER BY`; however, the rule in SQL is order is only guaranteed when you specify an `ORDER BY` on your final result.

As a grand total would be misleading/irrelevant in this case, I've dropped that. If you have more data and want to see year-over-year percentage changes, I'd consider separate queries.

Here's the final [DB-Fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wLDMS3HyMkQCjxAQeKgvcJ/1), showing both queries running.

Comment: Hi RDFozz, thanks for the posting tips and for the explanation, it was very detailed and has cleaned up my code a lot. I am still left with the initial problem of demonstrating the percentage increase month by month (if it is indeed possible).

With the ordered list that you have assisted with, is there an SQL query that will create a column showing a percentage increase (or decrease) on the previous month?

Comment: Updated w/ running percentage diff.

Comment: RDFozz you are an actual genius, thank you so much